# Generate first 10 Fibonacci numbers using infinite stream

Tags: clojure, fibonacci, lazy-sequences

I am trying to obtain the first 10 Fibonacci numbers as follows:

```
(take 10 (fn fibgen [a b] (cons a (fibgen b (+ a b))) 0 1))
```

The idea is that `fibgen` creates a lazy sequence (an infinite stream). Unfortunately this gives the following error:

> IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from:
> user$eval10144$fibgen__10145  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:528)

How can this be fixed?

Comment: you never call the function, and if you do call it it won't be lazy

Comment: @noisesmith I see now indeed. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just made a typo. Here's what your `fibgen` function looks like reformatted:

```
(fn fibgen [a b]
  (cons a (fibgen b (+ a b)))
  0
  1)
```

This function realizes the entire Fibonacci sequence starting with `a` and `b`, then returns 1. What you meant to do was define a function that returns the sequence, *call* it with 0 and 1, and then take the first ten items from that sequence:

```
(take 10 ((fn fibgen [a b] (cons a (fibgen b (+ a b)))) 0 1))
```

If you run this, you'll get an `ArithmeticException` for integer overflow, because numbers in the Fibonacci sequence quickly leave the range of a 64-bit integer. You can fix this using [`+'`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/+'):

```
(take 10 ((fn fibgen [a b] (cons a (fibgen b (+' a b)))) 0 1))
```

Since Clojure isn't lazy, this will try to realize the *entire* Fibonacci sequence, which will cause a `StackOverflowError`. Even though Clojure itself isn't lazy, though, you *can* create a [lazy sequence](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/lazy-seq), which will have basically the same effect in this case:

```
(take 10 ((fn fibgen [a b] (lazy-seq (cons a (fibgen b (+' a b))))) 0 1))
;;=> (0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34)
```

Comment: Thank you. One more question I hope you can answer: if Clojure is not lazy, why does `map` create a lazy seq? See [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36715935/code-not-called-from-go-block-but-it-works-from-repl#36717600).

Comment: Clojure is a strict language, which means that values are, by default, stored in a realized form rather than being stored as thunks that are realized only when needed. However, this doesn't mean you can't use thunks; the [`map`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2618-L2665) function uses the [`lazy-seq`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L664-L671) macro, which wraps a piece of code into a nullary function and returns an object that will call that function (and cache its result) only when asked to do so.